# Wix MSI installer fail when changing build image in Azure Pipelines

Tags: wix, azure-pipelines, wix3.10

As noted [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/removing-older-images-in-azure-pipelines-hosted-pools/) a bunch of legacy images in Azure Pipelines are being removed in a few days. We have had some code using [WIX](https://wixtoolset.org) building in Azure Pipelines for a few years now - using one of the images being deprecated (vs2015-win2012r2).

If I change my build image to e.g. vs2017-win2016, I get this error from my Azure Pipeline:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets(2439,7): Error
MSB4064: The "AllowDuplicateDirectoryIds" parameter is not supported by the "Light" task. 
Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
```

UPDATE:

I can now also reproduce this locally. And I have found out that one of the changes from WIX 3.10x to 3.11x is this particular parameter:

`AllowDuplicateDirectoryIds`

[image]

I can also see that the Azure Pipeline image [vs2017-win2016](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md) has WIX3.11 whereas the [Vs2015-Server2012R2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/d80f81d6c98f8ce2c74b034309bb774ea8d31cfb/images/win/Vs2015-Server2012R2-Readme.md) has WIX3.10 installed.

So everything fits ... my solution fails to build because it was targeted WIX 3.10 but the new image has WIX 3.11 installed.

So something inside my C# installer project still references Wix 3.10 and fails because the new 3.11 has some functionality that Wix 3.10 did not have.

What could that be?

Answer (score 1):

As what you found, the wix version that `vs2017-win2016` image used is `3.11`. And also, unfortunately, we does not support to install customized `wix` version to override the one that located in Hosted agent until now.

In your scenario, you can consider to use one work around: set up [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to build your project. Just ensure it is `wix 3.10` exists in your local machine that private agent installed.

When build with this private agent, the system will detect corresponding tools from local system. So, it would be succeed if you ensure there has `wix 3.10` located in the machine that private agent located.